# There is an app or a trick to emulate Portrait Effect on non plus iPhones?

Tags: software, portrait, light, effect, iphone

I love the "portrait effect" on my iPhone 8 Plus. Is there an app for the other iPhone models which can emulate it?

I'm specifically interested in two things:

- Background bokeh
- Studio lights

Here are some examples: 
[link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/z4qq7qu1hfcopyd/AAAUPFRBhqgF_FdQP-3gQ7_na?dl=0)

Captura 3 -> Image without the effect
Captura  -> Portrait effect (Bokeh in the background)
Captura 2 -> Portrait effect and B&W and studio lights

Comment: I think you misunderstand the term bokeh...and so we misunderstand what effect you are trying to achieve. Bokeh is the quality of out-of-focus parts of an image. What do you mean when you talk about the bokeh in these images? When I look at your "Captura 2", I just see a black background!

Comment: Sorry @osullic, there is Captura the one with bokeh.

Comment: The difference between Captura and Captura3 appears to be primarily framing, white balance and aperture, while Captura2 has some obvious additional external lighting (flashlight? snooted speedlight?) that has a definite focus.

Comment: @twalberg That's the whole point - the app on the iPhone 8 Plus is *simulating* the external lighting.

Comment: @PhilipKendall If there isn't actually any additional external lighting, then I think what you want to search for is "vignetting"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a couple of apps that do similar effect: 
-Phocus: portrait mode editor
-Patch

Source:
[link](https://www.applesfera.com/aplicaciones-ios-1/con-esta-app-puedes-imitar-el-modo-retrato-en-cualquier-iphone)